# JSON Data Could Not Read

Tags: c#, json, post

I have a Post Method as `GetProductList`, I post some inputs and the method filtered the data and returns a list. I try this method on Postman with JSON. I post the inputs but they come `null`. I add the debug ss. Why this happen?

Method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("GetProductList")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductList(int id, string? productName, string? companyName, int productInfo, int operationType, string? startDate, string? endDate)
        {
            var result = _productsService.GetProductList(id,productName, companyName, productInfo, operationType, startDate, endDate);

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

JSON:

```
{"id":152,"productName":null,"companyName":"XCompany","productInfo":5,"startDate":"2021-08-03","endDate":"2021-08-03","operationType":1}
```

ScreenShot from debugging

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a good idea to create a viewmodel, especially when you use post

```
public class ProductViewModel
{

public int Id {get; set;}
public string ProductName {get; set;}
public string CompanyName {get; set;}
.....

}
```

and when you use a Postman it is always good to try to add [FromBody]

```
[HttpPost]
 [Route("GetProductList")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductList([FromBody] ProductViewModel viewModel)
 {
 var result = _productsService.GetProductList(viewModel.Id,viewModel.ProductName, ....);

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

you can remove [FromBody] after testing, if it is not working in net

Comment: Your solution works, but I don't understand why my approach doesn't work

Comment: @mordeby You have to use [FromBody] attribute. You can try to use it for each property, but I never did it before and I am not sure if it is going to work.